# Run JavaScript inside of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to get the truck to drive across the screen Directly under my nav menu in Wordpress. The code executes perfectly in js fiddle , but when I try to load the JavaScript file, all I get is a still image (JavaScript is not loading)

Here is the working js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2RPq/60/

Here is the code I applied to page.php:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pimpdaddy1337.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/john.js"></script>
<div id="animate">
<img id="plane" src="http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/507037/507037,1274380827,2/stock-vector-black-and-white-big-rig-silhouette-53528596.jpg" /></div>
</script>
```

**CSS**

`css :#animate { position: relative;}`

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Are you aware that jQuery should be loaded inside the HEAD-section?

Comment: I guess you're talking about *javascript*, not *java*. Those are totally unrelated, even though javascript has java in its name for whatever reason (actually the reason is a similar syntax, but C has that, too...)

Comment: Im currently learning as i go, I changed jquery location to header.php and still no luck

Comment: I relocated my .js file to the header also , and it works perfectly

Comment: Do all javascript files have to be in the header ?

Comment: @JohannesH. "Whatever reason" in this case is marketing... which probably helped give JavaScript wider acceptance, but has resulted in unending confusion.

Comment: @JohnStidham `<script>` tags are valid inside the `<body>` and inside the `<head>` (but not inside any other element, so they have to be directly inside body or head, not nested). But note that the script isn't loaded (and therefore available or executed) before that part of the document was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding jQuery and Wordpress...

First, you should never load jQuery using the `<script>` tag when using Wordpress.   Wordpress has it's own method for how stuff should be loaded.   You can read more about there here:   http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Second, you may already have jQuery loaded in your Wordpress.   Wordpress themes frequently already have jQuery installed, but it runs in *No Conflict* mode.   This means that instead of using `$` in your functions, you need to write out `jQuery`.

Hopefully that gives you a starting point troubleshoot...

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't need to load jQuery, WordPress should load a version already.
- You have an extra `</script>` at the end of your html that doesn't appear to belong.
- Make sure you place your script tag `<script src="//pimpdaddy1337.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/john.js"></script>` inside of your `<head>` tag in header.php, try right before the line `</head>`.
- Make sure your div is placed in page.php (assuming that's the correct template file). You should be able to see it even if the script isn't firing, and if you can't there is some other problem.